# TypeError: Cannot set property 'sorting' of undefined..This is the error iam getting when i try to sort my id's in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**This is the error I am getting when I try to sort my id's in the database**

Below is the code snippet for which it is giving me an error

```js
router.post('/reorder-pages', function(req, res) {

    var ids = req.body['id[]'];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var id = ids[i];
        count++;

        (function(count) {

            Page.findById(id, function(err, page) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                page.sorting = count; //This is the line that is showing error 
                page.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                });

            });
        })(count);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that you are executing `page.sorting = count;` even if there is no document found on that particular `id`.
So something like this might save your day

```
router.post('/reorder-pages', function(req, res) {

  var ids= req.body['id[]'];
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < ids.length ; i++){
    var id = ids[i];
    count++;

    (function(count){
      
      Page.findById(id, function (err,page){
       
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
           page.sorting = count;  //This is the line that is showing error 
           page.save(function(err){
            if(err){
              return console.log(err);
            }
        });
        }
        
        
      });
    }) (count);
  }
  
});
```

So here we are only accessing `page object` if the page is found with the particular id and then saving it.

Comment: I got another error like this
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5f105c0553fc5a3e44cdd020 " at path "_id" for model "Page"

Comment: if you look closely there is a space after `20` in `"5f105c0553fc5a3e44cdd020 "`, so this is not a valid id, hence the error

Comment: Can u Please tell me how to fix it then

Comment: You can use `trim()` method. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp